# How to split a single polyline shapefile into many shapefiles based on unique value using GeoPandas?

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, pandas

I have a single polyline shapefile with multiple features (row). I want to export each row to separate shapefile with using GeoPandas. But I got Geometry error in the code. This is my shapefile:

[image]

and this is the code:

```
Work_directory = r'P:/directory/Test/20200812'
folder_out = Work_directory + "/00_processing"
Shp_UniqueRun= Work_directory + "/SHP/UniqueRuns1.shp"
gdf = gpd.read_file(Shp_UniqueRun) 

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    s = gdf.loc[index,'UniqueRun'] #use it for the name of output shapefiles
    shp_output = folder_out + "/" + str(s) + ".shp" #output shapefile
    NewSHP = gpd.GeoDataFrame(row)
    NewSHP.to_file(shp_output)
```

error:

```
AttributeError: No geometry data set yet (expected in column 'geometry'.)
```

Comment: Use `os.path.join` to combine paths, the way you are doing it might cause invalid paths. What is `type(gdf)`?

Comment: @BERA the type of gdf is <class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'> and Shp_UniqueRun is a polyline shapefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem `gdf.loc` is returning a Series and not a dataframe and `NewSHP = gpd.GeoDataFrame(row)` does not generate a valid geodataframe.

Try this instead to return a one row geodataframe:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file('/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/ak_riks.shp')

for i in df.index:
    subdf = df.iloc[[i]] #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990001/forcing-pandas-iloc-to-return-a-single-row-dataframe/45990057
    subdf.to_file('/home/bera/GIS/Data/testdata/out/Outshape_{0}.shp'.format(i))
```

[image]